# One event will not fired if i run RaiseEvent in the same time

Tags: vb.net, vb6, interop

I got an an issue when using the InteropUserControl: On the InteropUserControl if i raise 2 events at the same time, the Vb6 app will missing one of them. Below is the step to reproduce the behavior:

On VB.NET i created an InteropUserControl :

```
Public Event TestEvent()

 Public Sub RaiseTestEvent()
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
 End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        RaiseEvent TestEvent()
    End Sub
```

On Vb6, i created 2 InteropUserControl and using this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.InteropUserControl1.RaiseTestEvent
Me.InteropUserControl2.RaiseTestEvent
End Sub

Private Sub InteropUserControl1_TestEvent()
MsgBox "InteropUserControl1 fired"
End Sub
Private Sub InteropUserControl2_TestEvent()
MsgBox "InteropUserControl2 fired"
End Sub
```

What i received is just one event is fired and the other is missing. Is there any good solution for not missing these event?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Public Async Function RaiseTestEvent() As Task
    Await DoSomethingHere
    RaiseEvent TestEvent
End Function
```

If `DoSomethingHere` is not Async, then change that line to `Await Task.Run(Sub() DoSomethingHere)`